# Should PCBs be rinsed after being cleaned with IPA?

Tags: pcb, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly

A lot of people recommend using 99% IPA to clean flux (and other stuff) off PCBs. I haven't been rinsing off boards after cleaning with IPA as to my knowledge it's not corrosive, but I'd like to hear from someone more experienced on the matter.

Should I be rinsing boards with something like distilled water after cleaning them with 99% IPA?

Comment: Not only is IPA not corrosive, but it doesn't leave any residue - it evaporates entirely, like water.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IPA is pretty safe and non-corrosive. However, if you just let the board dry some flux residue will stay on the surface after IPA evaporates (since it was diluted in IPA during cleaning) making board surface sticky and less shiny. You can wash the board again in clean IPA, or water (use a dishwasher if you're using lead-free solder), or blow away IPA/dirt from the board with compressed air @70+ psi - that's what I do since it's the fastest way.

Comment: +1. I would also like to add another option - I like to keep cheaper grades of IPA around just for such an occasion. Something like 10%. It's a habit I kept from the navy, but it's basically just distilled water that dries faster.

Comment: I have noticed the residue left on the board but wasn't sure how to get it off.